# Filter bag by parent value in Apache PIG

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have the following relation in Apache PIG.

```
TSERIES: {ORDERED: {(timestamp: long,contentHost: chararray)},ts1: long}
```

And I want to do the following:

```
F = foreach TSERIES {
    ts = filter ORDERED by timestamp > TSERIES.ts1;
    generate ts;
}
```

In short, I want to keep all elements of bag ORDERED with a timestmap higher than ts1,
but pig won't allow, specifically this part `ts = filter ORDERED by timestamp > TSERIES.ts1;`.

Is this possible? I'm using version `0.9.2-cdh4.0.1` (cloudera).

Comment: Does ts1 happen to be unique for each tuple by any chance?

Comment: I have no strong guarantees, but I'd say it's unique for 99%. Since it's a timestamp, there's no hard rule that say that two timestamps cannot be exactly the same in this case (clickstream data).

Comment: I have the same issue with pig 0.14. Did you find a way to make it work ?

Comment: I think I used an UDF.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried :

Test = filter tseries By (ordered.timestamp > ts1);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this without a UDF... it seems like there should be, but I can't figure it out either. Anyway, you could either write a UDF to do this directly: go through the bag, filter out some, and return a bag. Or, you could write a UDF to generate UUIDs and then flatten the bag and re-group it - smoething like this:

```
a = foreach TSERIES generate ORDERED, ts1, myudfs.GenerateUUID() as id;
b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(ORDERED) as ts, ts1, id;
c = filter b by ts.timestamp > ts1;
d = group c by id;
```